# Implicit conversion changes signedness

Tags: objective-c

I have this warning from the compiler:

```
Implicit conversion changes signedness: 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') to 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int')
```

Which comes from this code:

```
- (NSInteger) tableView:(__unused UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(__unused NSInteger)section {
    return [_data count];
}
```

I understand the warning (it is weird that the delegate method expects a NSInteger, but just the way it is). If I cast [_data count] to a NSInteger is this the right way to do silence the warning?

It could (very unlikely, but since I'm learning) a buffer overflow. Since the cast will reduce the amount of possible values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's okay to make the cast; that indicates that you intentionally are doing the conversion.

This won't cause a buffer overflow.  What it may do is cause, in exceptional cases, the value to be lower than you expect (as an `NSUInteger` can hold a larger positive value than a `NSInteger`).

However, given the actual use of this delegate in a `UITableView`, that's so unlikely as to be, for all intents and purposes, impossible.

Comment: There is a post about this on apple dev forums. Even `NSUInteger` can't usually hold more positive values than `NSInteger` because `NSNotFound` is defined as `NSIntegerMax` (not `NSUIntegerMax`) which effectively limits the values returned from most Foundation methods. Buffer overflow is then very unlikely, especially here...

Comment: @Sulthan - that's quite an interesting observation.  I imagine it's defined that way for precisely this reason; it would be far too easy to run into casting bugs if `NSNotFound` disappeared when cast to a `NSUInteger`...